# HTML Dropdown for Table Nav Bar

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. Any searches bring up dropdown menus with

```
<nav></nav>
```

Let's say this is my table (Functioning as a nav bar):

```
<table class="nav">
<tr>
<td><a href="index.html">Home</a></td>
<td><a href="/Videos">All</a></td>
<td><a href="spec.html">Specification</a></td>
<td><a href="chem.html">Chemistry</a></td>
<td><a href="bio.html">Biology</a></td>
<td><a href="phy.html">Physics</a></td>
<td><a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></td>
<td><a href="donate.html">Donate</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table.nav {
    border: 2px solid white;
    background-color: black;
}
```

How would I make it so that when I hover on it, it shows a dropdown menu with links? The reason I want to do it this way is because of styling and convenience.

Comment: there are many, many ways to do it. are you willing to use javascript or jQuery (even jQuery plugins) to achiev that?

Comment: I'm okay with using js, but I've never used jquery before. I mean, if it's an elegant solution with jquery, I'm willing to learn it.

Comment: If you're willing to learn Javascript and jQuery might as well put forth the effort to NOT use tables as a way to design a website.

Comment: It's a conscious decision. Also, I know JS, but I don't know JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use javascript. Also I don't recommend using tables for this, but that's your choice. Look at this example:

```css
.nav {
    border: 2px solid white;
    background-color: black;
}

.nav td { position: relative; }

.nav table,
.nav ul { 
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 300px;
    left: 0;
}

.nav td:hover table { display: table; /* or display: block; */ }
.nav td:hover ul { display: block; }
```

```html
<table class="nav">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/Videos">All</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item in list</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item in list</a></li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td><a href="spec.html">Specification</a></td>
        <td>
            <a href="chem.html">Chemistry</a>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#">Item in table</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#">Item in table</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td><a href="bio.html">Biology</a></td>
        <td><a href="phy.html">Physics</a></td>
        <td><a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></td>
        <td><a href="donate.html">Donate</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So, for e.g. Chemistry, if a user hovers over Chemistry, what would I edit to make Chemistry dropdown into say, 4 options?

Comment: @Aurora See my initial answer, I edited and added a dropdown menu (added both a `<ul>` and `<table>` because I'm not sure which you want).

Comment: Ah, it works! Thank you. Also, @wk_ , where it says width: Xpx;, how do you make it so that the width of the background is the same or a little bigger than the length of the longest option? I've set background-color-black;

Comment: and how would I go about adding a border, say a white one, to the dropdown? @wk_

Comment: To add a small white border to the dropdown `<ul>`, just style it with `border: 1px #fff solid`. But that's basic css. No offense, but it might be wise to follow a tutorial on basic html and css before you continue with your website.

Comment: Ahh, thank you. I was trying to add a border from the existing CSS for the dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend you to use a list for this, especially if the content is dynamically created by some sort of CMS of PHP code. A simpel **CSS only solution** is to create list within list items witch display on hover, i've used this myself on some simpel Wordpress menus in the past.

For the styling you could use something like this

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
}

nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
}

nav ul li ul li {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
```

The last part `nav ul li:hover` tells to display `nav ul li ul` from `display: none` to `display: block`, the menu items should appear.

You could use the following HTML markup. Of course you would have to do some styling to make this more attractive.

```
<nav>
    <!-- Start the listing of main items -->
    <ul>
        <li>Menu item 1</li>
        <li>Menu item 2
            <!-- Sub items include -->
            <ul>
                <li>Menu item 2.1</li>
                <li>Menu item 2.2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Menu item 3</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I tested this code before, should do the trick. Hope this will help you out, otherwise you would have to reconsider using some Javascript as suggested by cr0ss.